# Merge two image folders in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, jupyter-notebook, image-segmentation

I am trying to merge all .jpg images from the training and validation set for further analysis

[image: 1]

```
    train_img = glob.glob("/Users/prat/train/train2014/*.jpg")
    train_img.sort()
    val_img = glob.glob("/Users/prat/validation/val2014/*.jpg")
    val_img.sort()
    
    for f1 in train_img:
        for f2 in val_img:
                img1 = cv2.imread(f1)
                img2 = cv2.imread(f2)
               
                img_m1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                img_m2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                
                img_rgb = cv2.merge((img_m1, img_m2))
                cv2.imwrite("/Users/prat/coco_image/img_name.jpg",img_rgb)
```

```
errror : error: OpenCV(4.6.0) /Users/xperience/actions-runner/_work/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/modules/core/src/merge.dispatch.cpp:129: error: (-215:Assertion failed) mv[i].size == mv[0].size && mv[i].depth() == depth in function 'merge'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. It is interesting that you are trying to do something, but that is not a question; and the image (please [do not use images to show code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) anyway) does not help to understand any problem. It is also not clear what the task is. What do you mean by "merge the images"? Are you trying to put files from two different folders into the same folder? Are you trying to create an image that looks like the other images put next to each other? One that mashes the images together somehow? Something else?

Comment: i am trying to merge images from both (training+validation) folder and store into one folder in directory so that i can do same analysis(both folder images having unique id in it)

Comment: Okay, so what's wrong with just using your operating system to do it?

Comment: The script I wrote is not working so need a help with python script so that i can merge image(train = 82783)+(val = 40504) expected output will be  (all_image = 123287)

Comment: Okay, so what is the part of your script that is supposed to move the files? I only see code that tries to find the names of the files, sort and count them.

Comment: @Pratiksha put the code in the question itself. Otherwise how to copy and test?

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you the dimensions or the depths of the two images you are trying to merge, are different, i.e. incompatible.

I suggest you use the debugger to look at them, or print them.

I think you are going to have trouble on the next line too, as saving a 2-channel image as a 3-channel RGB JPEG might be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, it was my first question on the stack and I am glad that I received a quick response however, I am not sure if it's logical or not but I have copied all train images to validation and it gave me desired output and I have ignored the train data.

```
import glob
import shutil
import os

src_dir = "/Users/prat/train/train2014/"
dst_dir = "/Users/prat/validation/val2014/"
for jpgfile in glob.iglob(os.path.join(src_dir, "*.jpg")):
    shutil.copy(jpgfile, dst_dir)
```

[Desired output acheived](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfPMK.png)